# How to validate only the first record from a form in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm using cakephp 2.0, I have two models: Client and proposals.

The proposed model is related to HasMany Client;
The Model Client is related to the proposal using belongsTo;

Inserted in the two fields to view customer base but would like to validate the presence of only the first client in the proposal.

I've tried several ways but I can not do it.

How could perform this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "presence of only the first client in the proposal." The statement leads me to believe that you are looking for the first client in an ordered list (rather that simply if there are 1 or more records).

Below are ways you could approach it based on the two different approaches I can infer from your question:

1) You are simply looking to see if there is a client attached to a proposal.

You could implement counter_cache in your clients model so that you don't even need to look at the client model when you query a proposal.  If the value is zero, then there is no client:

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
     'proposal' => array(
         'counter_cache' => true
      )
 );
```

Or you can see if the client array is greater than zero after you find your proposal;

```
 $proposal = $this->Proposal->findById($proposalId);
 if(sizeof($proposal['Client'])>0){ //Do this }
```

2) Find the "first" client based on whatever order you have setup.

Make both models "containable."

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then in your find statement, do this..

```
$this->Proposal->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array( //conditions for the proposal you want ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Client' => array(
                'order' => array( //order statement to get the first client ),
                'limit' => 1
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Scott thanks for the reply,

What I would do however is to validate only the registration of the first client, and there were two on my form fields to fill in customer data.

I managed to do this by creating a custom validation in the model client.

Yet thanks!